# Install apache cloudstack Management Server

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I'm trying to install apache cloudstack management server on centos 6.9. As instructions provided i've configured yum repository with;

```
*[cloudstack]
name=cloudstack
baseurl=http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/centos/6/4.9/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0*
```

Now when I'm going to install management server with command;

```
*yum install cloudstack-management*
```

I get the message;

```
*Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.btte.net
 * extras: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * updates: mirror.bit.edu.cn
base                                      | 3.7 kB     00:00     
cloudstack                                | 3.2 kB     00:00     
extras                                    | 3.3 kB     00:00     
updates                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
**No package cloudstack-management available.
Error: Nothing to do***
```

I'm so new with cloudstack and i'm almost stacked with this problem. Please advice how resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to clean repository first:

```
# yum clean all
```

Then try installing it again:

```
# yum install cloudstack-management
```

If it still does not work, download the rpms cloudstack-management and cloudstack-common

```
# wget http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/centos/6/4.9/cloudstack-management-4.9.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

# wget http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/centos/6/4.9/cloudstack-common-4.9.2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Now install the packages manually:

```
  # rpm -ivh cloudstack-*
```

Once it is installed, you may proceed with next steps on management server installation page.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some problem in your system or network.
I suggest you to download all files and dirs to your centos, and modify your repo file set url as "baseurl=file:///DIRPATH_YOU_SOTRE_RPMS"